# How to save Ubuntu server configuration to easily recreate server in the future

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver

A few months ago I spun up a Linux server which runs a Django application on a web hoster. (Ubuntu 16.4, nginx, django)

The need for this server is not present anymore and I would like to save the money and shut it down.

However, in the future I might need it again and am therefore looking for best practices how I can "save" the current state of the server (Ubuntu configuration, nginx config) to simply spun it up again should I need it in the future. Something along the lines of creating an image of the server that can be applied again or saving the config files. I also heard about docker and was wondering if that offers an option to save it easily.

I am sure this is a very common use case but due to my lack of experience I could not find suitable solutions probably because I do not know the right vocabulary for what I am looking for.

Any help, advice and suggestion appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is to use `tar` to create full system archive. A simple command like `cd /; tar --one-file-system --exclude=./mnt/* -czpvf /mnt/backup.tar.gz ./` should do, but you will get a pretty large file to download.